# perl open file error handling

Tags: perl

I want to do some task when the file is not opened in the Perl program below. But when I run it, I am getting syntax errors. What's wrong with it?

```
my $LOGPATH = $ENV{DATA_OU};
my $LOGFILE =  "cdj_rep" . "." . "test" . ".rpt";

if ! (open(OUT,">$LOGPATH/test1/work/$LOGFILE")) {
   print "testin";
   return;  
}

close(OUT);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ! needs to go inside the brackets:

```
if (! open (out,
```

Answer (score 15):

I'd write it as

```
my $LOGPATH = $ENV{DATA_OU};
my $LOGFILE = "cdj_rep.test.rpt";
my $path    = "$LOGPATH/test1/work/$LOGFILE";

open my $fh, ">", $path or do {
  warn "$0: open $path: $!";
  return;
};

close $fh or warn "$0: close $path: $!";
```

Place the entire path in `$path` so you don't have to repeat it multiple times, and if you ever need to change it, you can do so in one place.

The call to `open` uses a lexical filehandle (`my $fh`) rather than a bareword handle. This is a good habit to develop because passing `$fh` to subs or stuffing it inside data structures tends to be more natural syntactically.

It also uses the 3-argument form of `open` so you don't have to worry about characters in the path being interpreted specially. It may not seem like a big deal in the context of your code, but it's another good habit to develop.

A common idiom for checking whether an `open` succeeds is

```
open my $fh, "<", $path
  or die "$0: open $path: $!";
```

Using `if (!open ...` or `unless (open ...` would be fine, but with a lexical filehandle, you need to worry about scoping issues. You seem to be using the check as a guard, so writing `open or ...` leaves the filehandle in scope for when it does succeed. You want two statements to execute if it fails, so you need to wrap them in `do { ... }` as above.

Also note the content of the error message passed to `warn`:

- the program that had an error (`$0`)
- what it was trying to do (`open $path`)
- and why it failed (`$!`)

The `warn` and `die` operators send their output to the standard error, which allows the flexibility of redirecting error messages elsewhere.

Finally, when you `close` a handle on a file you created to write or append, you should check whether it fails, which might happen if an I/O error occurred, for example.

Comment: Schwern says we should use `autodie`.

Comment: +1: well written recommendation for the newer, better Perl open techniques.

Comment: Thanks for throwing light over $0 and $! inbuilt variables. Very useful for newbies like me.

Also, isn't it a convention to use uppercase FILE_HANDLES?

Comment: @SidSarasvati Using uppercase bareword `FILE_HANDLES` in Perl is old-fashioned and has several drawbacks, *e.g.*, they are global in scope and are awkward to store in data structures or pass as parameters. Please use lexical filehandles.