# executing perl script from python

Tags: python, perl, unix

I`m trying to executo Perl script from python script, but it seems like it has not been executed!
using this command in python:

```
os.popen('dump_hash.pl {}'.format(scn_filepath))
```

this is the dump_hash.pl script:

```
$path = <STDIN>;
require "$path";
open (OUTFILE, "+>dumpered_hash");
print OUTFILE Dumper("\%...");
close (OUTFILE);
```

and the script stucks when trying to open 'dumpered_hash' as readable file. and when I run ls command in shell, the directory doesn`t have dumpered_hash file.

thanks you.

Comment: how can the script "not been executed" and yet "stucks when trying to open"? If it is a problem with opening the file for output, maybe these links will help you: http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html#ERROR-HANDLING http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233327/perl-open-file-error-handling - otherwise, can you provide more detailed information? What works, what not, how was which script called, etc. Also paste exact error messages

Comment: my mistake, it stuck at os.popen(..) command.

Comment: What about using `subprocess.call('perl dump_hash.pl')` using the `subprocess` python module?

Comment: subprocess.Popen('dump_hash.pl {}'.format(scn_filepath)), tried subprocess.call it didn`t work, gives the same error.

Comment: If you're running under *nix, you may want to add a `#!` line to the beginning of the .pl file otherwise your OS has little reason to guess it's Perl.

Comment: Yea I have it. now it running well, instead of using <STDIN> I used $ARGV[0], as @amon said. bue ARGV[0] has nothing!! i`m using os.popen('dump_hash.pl {}'.format(scn_filepath))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Perl script is wrong:

- You read the path from STDIN, not from the command line arguments.
- You do not remove the newline after reading a line. You would be looking for `"foo\n"` instead of `"foo"`.
- You have no error checking whatsoever.
- You do not load the `Data::Dumper` module.

And are you sure that you really want to execute the file at `$path` as Perl code?

Cleaned up, I'd write the Perl script as

```
perl -MData::Dumper \
  -do $ARGV[0];' \
  -e'print Dumper \%some_global' \
  input-file.pl >output
```

Or as

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper
do $ARGV[0];
open my $fh, ">", "output" or die "Can't open output: $!";
print { $fh } Dumper \%some_global;
```

If you really want the filename from STDIN:

```
 use strict; use warnings;
 use Data::Dumper;
 chomp(my $path = <STDIN>);
 do $path;
 ...
```

Comment: the path is for a file that contains complex hash table name /../hash.pl . i have loaded the dumper and i have warnings. i need to require the the file in the path.

Comment: `require` and `do` are equivalent for this purpose.

Comment: still, it not running. the script doesn`t creat any files. and if create files for it, it doesn`t write anything to them.  BTW, the script was checked with require to the file with full path. and it worked.